# Trying to adapt script to use ControlSend

Tags: autohotkey

So I have this simple script that sends the Space keypress every 5 seconds

```
#NoEnv
#singleinstance force
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

SetTimer, PressTheKey2, 5000
Return
z::exitapp

PressTheKey2:
Send, {Space down}
Sleep 50
Send, {Space up}
```

This works but I want to use ControlSend to adapt this, and send the input directly to my desired window, in this case nba 2k23.
But when i try to use the following code, nothing happens. Unsure if maybe I misunderstood ControlSend

```
PressTheKey:
ControlSend,, {Space down}, NBA2K23.exe
Sleep 50
ControlSend,, {Space up}, NBA2K23.exe
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [WinTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm). Right now you're trying to use a window's with a title "NBA2K23.exe". I doubt the game's window title is that. You're of course thinking of the game executable. If you want to match a window by it's executable instead of the title, you need the `ahk_exe` identifier.

```
ControlSend,, {Space down}, ahk_exe NBA2K23.exe
Sleep 50
ControlSend,, {Space up}, ahk_exe NBA2K23.exe
```

If it still doesn't work, it can be normal. `ControlSend` can be a hit or a miss, especially with games. A game might process input in an other way which would make `ControlSend` ineffective.

If you want to make sure you're doing it correct, you can try this with the default Windows notepad open:

```
ControlSend, , asd, ahk_exe notepad.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! i've tried your suggestion and i believe that it doesn't work with this game. Would there be another way to send that script to the game, while it is out of focus?